# how to protect the emails from your domain, to be used as FROM fields

Tags: email

we have severals domains, with their corresponding servers hosted on linux (ubuntu).

sendmail lets you send emails, allowing for changing of the envelope.
Here a simple example - which works with no extra settings:

```
sendmail -f bill.gates@microsoft.com -t destination@example.com
```

is there a way to stop others from using any email adresses registered with our domains?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to stop others from using any email adresses registered with our domains?

You can't *stop* them, but you can make it more difficult (i.e. increase the chance it will be caught and marked as spam).

This is what [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) has been designed for (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)):

> Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is an email validation system designed
>   to prevent email spam by detecting email spoofing, a common
>   vulnerability, by verifying sender IP addresses. SPF allows
>   administrators to specify which hosts are allowed to send mail from a
>   given domain by creating a specific SPF record (or TXT record) in the
>   Domain Name System (DNS).